# MYSQL query based on multiple HTML Checkboxes

Tags: mysql, checkbox

I have a table containing soil analysis, around 400k rows, with about 30 columns. All rows have a Year column, where it says something between 1997 and 2014.

I let the user do a MySQL query based on a couple of HTML-forms and one checkbox for each year.
If no checkbox is filled it searches through every year in the table.
My intention is to let the user be able to select a specific year or several with the help of the checkboxes.

I have copied what i have right now. (I've excluded the variables and stuff, excuse the swedish here and there)
The HTML-forms work fine. But i haven't figured how to take use of the checkboxes yet. I have no idea how to implement them in the MySQL query. I've tried googling but the question seems kinda specific in my case.
I'd be really happy to hear your opinion in the matter.

```
        <form id="form" action="statisticsToMap.php" method="post">
            <p>______Minimum_____________Maximum______</p>
            <p>pH: <input type="text" name="min-ph" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">  pH: <input type="text" name="max-ph" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></p>
            <p>P-AL: <input type="text" name="min-p" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">  P-AL: <input type="text" name="max-p" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></p>
            <p>K-AL: <input type="text" name="min-k" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">  K-AL: <input type="text" name="max-k" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></p>
            <p>Mg-AL: <input type="text" name="min-mg" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">  Mg-AL: <input type="text" name="max-mg" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></p>
            <p>Lerhalt: <input type="text" name="min-ler" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">  Lerhalt: <input type="text" name="max-ler" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></p>
            <p>Sand-Grovmo: <input type="text" name="min-sgrovmo" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">  Sand-Grovmo: <input type="text" name="max-sgrovmo" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></p>
            <p>Mullhalt: <input type="text" name="min-mull" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">  Mullhalt: <input type="text" name="max-mull" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></p>
            <p>Klicka i vilka årtal som du vill söka efter: (tomma rutor söker alla årtal)</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="1997" value="1997"> 1997
            <input type="checkbox" name="1998" value="1998"> 1998
            <input type="checkbox" name="1999" value="1999"> 1999
            <input type="checkbox" name="2000" value="2000"> 2000
            <input type="checkbox" name="2001" value="2001"> 2001<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="2002" value="2002"> 2002
            <input type="checkbox" name="2003" value="2003"> 2003
            <input type="checkbox" name="2004" value="2004"> 2004
            <input type="checkbox" name="2005" value="2005"> 2005
            <input type="checkbox" name="2006" value="2006"> 2006<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="2007" value="2007"> 2007
            <input type="checkbox" name="2008" value="2008"> 2008
            <input type="checkbox" name="2009" value="2009"> 2009
            <input type="checkbox" name="2010" value="2010"> 2010
            <input type="checkbox" name="2011" value="2011"> 2011<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="2012" value="2012"> 2012
            <input type="checkbox" name="2013" value="2013"> 2013
            <input type="checkbox" name="2014" value="2014"> 2014
            <input type="checkbox" name="2015" value="2015"> 2015
            <input type="checkbox" name="2016" value="2016"> 2016<br>
            <p>Begränsa antal resultat:</p> <input type="text" name="limitrows" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"> (Standard är 2000 rader)<br><br>

            <table>
                <tr>
                <input type="submit" value="Sök i databas"onclick="submitForm('')">
                <input type="submit" value="Visa resultat på karta" onclick="submitForm('statisticsToMap.php')">
                </form>
                </tr>
            </table>


 $sql = "SELECT `kundnr`, `Year`, `Provnr`, `pH`, `P_AL`, `P_HCl`, `K_AL`, `K_HCl`, `Mg_AL`,     
        `Cu_HCl`, `K_Mg_kvot`, `Bor`, `Ca_AL`, `Total_lerhalt`, `Sand_grovmo`, `Mullhalt` 

        FROM `analyser`

        WHERE 


            (IFNULL(`pH`,               '0')    BETWEEN $minph      AND $maxph)
        AND (IFNULL(`P_AL`,             '0')    BETWEEN $minpal     AND $maxpal)
        AND (IFNULL(`K_AL`,             '0')    BETWEEN $minkal     AND $maxkal)
        AND (IFNULL(`Mg_AL`,            '0')    BETWEEN $minmg      AND $maxmg)
        AND (IFNULL(`Total_lerhalt`,    '0')    BETWEEN $minler     AND $maxler)
        AND (IFNULL(`Mullhalt`,         '0')    BETWEEN $minmull    AND $maxmull)
        AND (IFNULL(`Sand_grovmo`,      '0')    BETWEEN $minsgrovmo AND $maxsgrovmo)

        LIMIT 0,$limitrows";
```

/Simon

Comment: Would it make things terribly slow to just return the entire dataset, and handle ALL the filtering/pagination client-side (e.g. in ajax/PHP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that simply be the case where you will dynamically build a `YEAR IN (..)` clause based on the year selection? E.g. when 2008, 2010 and 2012 were selected:

`SELECT * FROM SOIL_DATA WHERE YEAR IN (2008, 2010, 2012)`

Comment: Thanks. I did use you're solution.
Added the years to a array used if and isset to check boxes. Then implode with ",".
Worked great.